# combine two and statements to get results needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two `AND` statements.

One of them includes a `CASE` statement which is needed in order to get the data I want from one of the referred code while not including the "Access" referred code.

The other `AND` statement is where I am wanting to bring in the data from the access including all others except the "No Access". How can I combine these to get the result I am looking for? I would really appreciate the help, thanks!

```
AND  CASE 
       WHEN ISNULL(t.refer,'') IN ('complete', 'late', 'missed') 
        AND t.refercode IN ('Access', 'Access-t') 
         THEN 0 
       ELSE 1 
     END = 1
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT pt.* FROM dbo.physicalstate pt 
                 WHERE  t.referID = pt.referID 
                 AND pt.referCODE IN ('off','closed')
                 AND t.referCODE IN ('Access')

AND ISNULL(t.refer,'') IN ('complete','late','missed')
AND t.refercode IN('access')
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT pt.* FROM dbo.physicalstate pt 
                 WHERE  t.referID = pt.referID 
                 AND pt.referCODE IN ('off','closed')
                 AND t.referCODE IN ('Access')
```

Comment: post the full query please.

Comment: Also show sample data and expected results. Have you looked into `UNION`?

Comment: BTW: there is no need for `ISNULL(t.refer,'')`. When `t.refer` is NULL it will automatically fall through to `ELSE` condition.